# my 2013 nissan altima is jerking back and forth and can hear ABS pump when hitting brakes

Tags: nissan, abs, altima

Hello last week i heard a weird noise almost like something was loose in the hood of my car (like a big pin bouncing around) two days after when I started my car but still in park my rpm meter was going up and the car started to jerk back and forth. When i place the car in drive and hit my gas to move, my ABS pump comes on and I can feel the brakes flooring down. 
My car drives but at the light I am sitting in a car that jerks back and forth while keeping my foot on the brake.
yesterday when I cut my car on, it shut off with my ac still running. I started it back up and hit the gas a couple of times. unfortunately, the shaking continued.  MY engine light is on
Last I noticed that my gas is burning up and soon will have to fill up my car

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!